# Trying to do a simple comparison, in python involving RFID, does not compare successfully

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, rfid

I have an RFID tag connected to my raspberry pi, I had written a test string to the RFID tag, the letters 'ab'.

```
def read():
    reader = SimpleMFRC522()
    #stores id number and a 'password' (ab is stored as text)
    try:
        id,text = reader.read()
    finally:
        GPIO.cleanup()
    return text

if __name__ == '__main__':
    password = read()
    print(password)
    if password == 'ab':
        print("password: "+password)
    else:
        print("Incorrect tag.")
```

When I run I get:

```
ab
Incorrect tag.
```

I should be getting
`password: ab`

In my program I have a read() function which just returns the text on the tag, 'ab'.

In main, I compare the variable assigned to read() with the string 'ab' and it should just print

`password: ab`
instead it is seen as incorrect, and goes to the else statement.

Does anyone know what this could be?

**What I've done:**

- I tried forcing both password and 'ab' as strings by wrapping str() around them, even though they already are strings.
- I've checked the type for password. It is a string.

  ```
  print(type(password))
  ```

I also changed the statement to

`if True:`

just to see if the print statement would execute. It did.

I'm not sure what this error would be considering there are no spaces in what I read to the tag, it is literally just the letters 'ab'

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.  For starters, print out the value of `password` at the problem point.  Check its type, check its length, etc.

Comment: interesting enough, printing out password's length, gave me 48. even though when I ```print(password)``` it gives ```ab```

Comment: *AHA!*  Well, there's a huge clue.  What is the type of `password` -- what is the unit of that `48` -- bytes, bits, meters, ... ?  If it's some sort of double-byte characters, it's possible that you have 3 characters of 16 bits ... but I'm brainstorming here.

Comment: password is a string! I actually just fixed my problem by making a new variable and adding the first two characters of password to that variable. Not very modular but it'll do for now! I'm wondering how all those extra characters got snuck in for the length to be that large and still only look like 2 characters when printed. Thanks for reminding me to do those basic tests. I should've checked the length 30 minutes ago lol

Comment: May be rest of 46 characters are spaces ? They are printing out but you can’t see’ek.

Answer (score 0):

You must use `strip()` function.

`if(password.strip() == "ab"):`
and it must work.